# Dance a song or dance to a song?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why?

A) Listen to this song! It's so good, I want to dance ***it***.

B) Listen to this song! It's so good, I want to dance ***to*** it.

C)I love this song. Can we dance ***to it***?

Comment: It could be any of those. A) means something different than either B) or C). They are all grammatical—although A) is a bit strange: it means that you want to express the song silently in dance rather than dancing in accompaniment to it.

Comment: Have you any supporting references for the use of 'dance' transitively other than with _cognate/hyponymic_ (danced the dance of death / danced a tango) _objects_?